# ST_Point query with Hive using Esri Geometry, FAILED

Tags: postgresql, hive, postgis, user-defined-functions, esri

When I do

```
Select ST_Point(25,45)
```

in PostgresQL I get the following :

```
010100000000000000000039400000000000804640
```

Whoever when I do the same thing in Hive I get this :

[image]

If that was the only problem I wouldn't mind but when I do

```
Select ST_Azimuth(ST_Point(25,45) , ST_Point(75,100))
```

I get this error :

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments '100': No matching method for class ST_Azimuth with (binary, binary).

Comment: it might be that hive (here I am stretching my knowledge) cannot cope with the data type `geometry`. Maybe a workaround with WKT would do the trick? `Select ST_Azimuth(ST_AsText(ST_Point(25,45)) ,ST_AsText(ST_Point(75,100)))` or even `Select ST_Azimuth(ST_AsText(ST_Point(25,45))::geometry ,ST_AsText(ST_Point(75,100))::geometry)`. It should actually work with the query you provided, since `ST_Point` already returns a geometry.

Comment: btw, `0.452 seconds` for such an operation is insanely slow.

Comment: Is ST_Azimuth a custom UDF you wrote? If so, please provide the code in the description

Comment: @SergeyKhudyakov I believe it is a postgis function that gets two geometries as parameters: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html

Comment: @JimJones The function ST_Azimuth takes geometry as parameter

Comment: @ChemsBezzaz thanks! But isn't it what I just said? :-D

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referencing the Hive spatial UDFs provided by [Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop)?

1. There is no geometry type in Hive and so the spatial UDFs return a binary representation of the geometry. As @JimJones commented, you can use `ST_AsText(geom)` to format the geometry as WKT.
2. Please use [one of the Hive spatial UDFs](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/blob/master/hive/src/main/java/com/esri/hadoop/hive/ST_AsText.java) as a reference for your [custom ST_Azimuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010121/error-occurs-while-using-a-hive-udf-that-calculate-the-azimuth) UDF that you are developing.